# How to insert multiple tabs string in java?

Tags: java, string

How to insert multiple tabs string in Java?

This example:
`getName() + '\t' + '\t' + getLastName()`, does not work.

Comment: Please explain *why* it doesn't work.  What error message did you get?

Comment: @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "\b"+ "\"" + getFamilyName() + 
     "\t"+"\t"+ "\t"+ "\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\"" + getCountry();
 }

Comment: Try to give some additional context.  Show us the methods for getName() and getLastName().  It will be much easier for us to help if you edit your answer in that fashion.

Comment: where are you displaying it?, can you try to do a http://sscce.org/ ?

Comment: Made a simple Java application in Eclipse that prints OP's string to System.out.

Worked perfectly. Not sure what "doesn't work" means, or what he/she's looking for.

Comment: @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "\b"+ "\"" + getFamilyName() + 
     "\t"+"\t"+ "\t"+ "\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\"" + getCountry();
 }

Comment: I'am working with play! frmawork , CRUD module

Comment: Please edit your original post to include these details. It's easier to have it all in one place than to have to search through the comments.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your example should work; however there's no reason to append each tab character individually. This works, too:

```
getName() + "\t\t" + getLastName();
```

The errors you are getting are not related to the tab characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is screwy. Try this.

```
 String whatever0 = "firstname"+"\t"+"\t"+"lastname";
 String whatever1 = "firstname"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"lastname";
 System.out.println(whatever0);
 System.out.println(whatever1);
```

You'll see that they give different results.