# Java compilation issues

Tags: java

I'm trying to carryout a simple velocity calculations.but my codes wouldn't compile.I'm not sure what's wrong with it. Any help will do me some good as i'm a newbie in Java.

```
public class VelocityFall
     {
public static void main (String [] a)
     {
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("This program prints a table that shows each \nsecond," 
     +
    "height from the ground (meters), and the velocity (m/s)\n of a free-  
    falling" + 
    "object from an initial height (metres).\nPlease input the Initial  
     Height H:  ");


    // input/get the value of H from the keyboard
    int H = s.nextInt ();
    // we need to design/output the table by using println with lines and   
    tabs (\t)

    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println (" Second\t\tHeight\t\tVelocity");
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------");

    //we now require a for loop
    for (int t = 0; t<=15; t++)
   {
    // we are now going to calculate and output the velocity
    double velocity = Math.sqrt(2*9.8*H);
    System.out.println (t++"\t\t"+H"\t\t"+velocity);

    }
   }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: `tabs (\t)` looks very suspicious.

Comment: And, `System.out.println(t + "\t\t" + H + "\t\t" + velocity);`

Comment: Drop the second `+` in `t++"\t\t"`

Comment: That's strange ... why do you post code which is obivously not the one you're running? The code in the picture doesn't has `tabs(\t)` or the additional line breaks in the first `System.out.println`.

Comment: Recompile it, by removing extra spaces
These are the method calls, to don't add space in b/w them.
As like below:
public static void main(String []a)

Comment: and please recompile your code, by removing "opening and closing braces", and show me the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your :

```
System.out.println (t++"\t\t"+H"\t\t"+velocity);
//--------------------^--------^
```

You need something like this:

```
System.out.println(t + "\t\t" + H + "\t\t" + velocity);
//-----------------^-^------------^
```

I think you want to make some tabs like this :

> Second ****Tab**** H ****Tab**** velocity

You can learn more here: [How to insert multiple tabs string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021435/how-to-insert-multiple-tabs-string-in-java)

You can get this result in the end:

```
This program prints a table that shows each 
second,height from the ground (meters), and the velocity (m/s)
 of a free-fallingobject from an initial height (metres).
Please input the Initial  Height H:  3
------------------------------------------
 Second     Height      Velocity
------------------------------------------
0       3       7.6681158050723255
1       3       7.6681158050723255
2       3       7.6681158050723255
3       3       7.6681158050723255
4       3       7.6681158050723255
5       3       7.6681158050723255
6       3       7.6681158050723255
7       3       7.6681158050723255
8       3       7.6681158050723255
9       3       7.6681158050723255
10      3       7.6681158050723255
11      3       7.6681158050723255
12      3       7.6681158050723255
13      3       7.6681158050723255
14      3       7.6681158050723255
15      3       7.6681158050723255
```

Comment: Please can you refer me to a very good java book/material?

Comment: @lee i think the best way is to practice more and more, and start with a project, so you can get many things from it, for books, i think this is not a good idea to learn one from the beginning, because there are many examples in google and youtube, so just start a simple project and when you find some problems you can find in google, because the best way to learn is the **practice** not just theory, hope you get my point, you can find many things here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topics

Comment: thanks alot. cheers

Comment: you are welcome @lee :)

Comment: I have another challenge, the code above provides the correct values .im working on something similar but I'm not getting it right. Im trying to calculate velocity and distance of a free falling object

Comment: I'm using there formulas with the uploaded codes but im not getting the expected result                                                                                      double velocity = 9.8*t;
H = (9.8*Math.pow(t,2))/2;

Comment: mmm, @lee can you post another question, i think this better to you, put another question and we will try to help you ok :)